# When I work on my branch, my pushes aren't showing up on GitHub

Tags: github, push

When I work on my branch, my pushes don't show up on GitHub, so the pushes don't turn GitHub progress graph boxes green. When I work in the main branch, everything is fine. Could somebody please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to merge your branch with the main branch. Or push both branches to github and make a pull request and merge the branches on github.
To push all your branches to github:

git push -u --all

now all your branches should appear

[image: Git branches]

After you pushed all your branches you can use a pull request to merge the 2 branches.[image: pull request]

Cick on New pull request.[image]

From the dropdowns select the branches you want to merge. And then click create pull request. A message box will appear. Write the commit message you want and click again Create pull Request.
After you have created the pull request[image: after pull request]

If you have no code conflicts. You should see the picture above. If there are code conflicts you need to either resolve them in your IDE or via the command line.

If you want to merge branches without pushing to github here is a useful link.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Comment: vielen Dank, ich versuchte es und mein problem wurde gelöst.